# Cambiar formato fecha/hora creacion fichero bash

Tags: bash

Necesito obtener en bash ciertos datos de ficheros logs que tengo preparados, para realizar un informe semanal. Entre otros datos, debo obtener la fecha de creación del log (empieza el proceso) y la fecha de fin del proceso. Ambas fechas las obtengo con head y tail.

El problema es que ambos comandos devuelven la fecha con formato aaaa-mm-dd, pero necesitaría sacarlos con formato dd/mm/aaaa.

¿De qué manera podría cambiar el formato obtenido?

Comment: Hay algo que no me es claro. La fecha que dices (inicio y fin), la lees de los archivos log en cuestión? Podrías poner un ejemplo o el código en el que usas `head` y `tail`?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner una línea de ejemplo para que quede más claro? Igualmente, un [mcve] sobre el problema general ya sería fantástico

Comment: Todos los ficheros logs empiezan y terminan de la siguiente forma:

`-- 2019-01-28 08:24:21.571439....`

Entonces, con head por ejemplo hago:

`finicio=$(head -n 1 $line | cut -d " " -f 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te podría servir para cambiar el formato usando esta manera:

```
date +"%d/%m/%Y"
```

Puedes conseguir mas información a través de este enlace : [Formato fecha](http://www.elmundoenbits.com/2013/04/date-format-bash-linux.html)

**Edit**

Pongo la `%y` en mayúsculas `%Y` para obtener el año con cuatro cifras en vez de dos. Ej: **2019**

Comment: Con date saco la fecha del sistema, yo necesito manejar fechas de un fichero

Comment: @lk2_89, no, también puedes usarlo para formatear una fecha desde una variable, por ejemplo: `date -d "$finicio" +"%d/%m/%Y"`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho voy a probarlo así, ¡muchas gracias!